# Converting accented characters from QString to std::string returns mangled text

Tags: utf-8, stdstring, qstring

If my QString's value is

```
WeŠ.txt
```

the function QString::toStdString() will return

```
WeÅ .txt
```

whereas the function QString::toStdU16String will return the actual string

```
WeŠ.txt.
```

Why is that ? Š is a UTF-8 character as can be seen here : http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting QString to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318443/converting-qstring-to-stdstring)